# Como inserir uma imagem/figura para uma forma do canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

O fragmento de código abaixo, desenha um retângulo no elemento canvas, e o preenche com a cor azul. Quero preencher com uma figura/imagem externa (como *background*). Tem como?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>

<script>
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle= "blue";
ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 150, 100);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, depois de pesquisar mais um pouco, descobri que o método  `CanvasRenderingContext2D.createPattern()` resolve. Ver [link do MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/createPattern)

Grato pela atenção!

Comment: Esse código pode ser uma solução para a pergunta, mas sua resposta pode ser melhor se você incluir uma explicação sobre os principais pontos do código. O objetivo não é ajudar apenas quem fez a pergunta, mas os próximos visitantes também. Leia mais em [Respostas apenas com código - O que fazer?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/7172/100416).